# Determine Default Gateway with Wired IPv6 address on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, networking, ipv6, gateway

I am trying to create a dual network connection via Wireless and ethernet. The wifi connection runs my internet and the ethernet connection is connected to router which is connected to a NAS. I've had this configuration working before, but i have recently purchased a new router - Actiontec Qwest Q1000. 
The problem that I am having is that when I connect to the router via ethernet I cannot determine the default gateway, I know the default is 192.168.0.1, but that doesn't work either. When i run:

```
netstat -r | grep default
```

I receive this output:

```
default            192.168.2.1        UGSc           14        0     en1
default            link#4             UCSI            0        0     en0
```

I have tried to make the IP static, but can't seem to work it out. From what i can gather any wired connection must use IPv6 and wireless uses IPv4. These pictures should demonstrate:

[image]

Also are my IPv6 settings correct:

[image]

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, most of the time with wired connection, you simply plug them in and away you go. Also below are two images of my network connection settings within system preferences:

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

Tried on ubuntu 12.10, worked fined, plugged in no worries

Comment: Please try the following command, sudo dhclient en0, then post the (whole) routing table *after* the connection is established.

Comment: Your ULA prefix is invalid. You should never use `fd00::/64`. You can go to e.g. https://www.sixxs.net/tools/grh/ula/ to generate an ULA prefix the correct way. For more information take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address

Comment: This appears to be two separate questions. Please consider editing this one to contain a single question, and posting the other question separately.

Comment: @Sander Steffann, tried that and also disabled this feature, still nothing. I'm thinking it could be a hardware issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OS X / macOS on non-apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed). See also [Revisit the Hackintosh policy](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12050/revisit-the-hackintosh-policy).

Answer (score -1):

The problem was hardware, I am running a Hackintosh and the ethernet driver - the Official Realtek 2.0.6 for 10.7 driver for 81xx Ethernet controllers, wasn't working properly. I'm not sure why, because it functioned with IPv4 DHCP tabels, I'm only guessing here but I belive the kext installed is not compatible with IPv6.

To solve the problem I installed the Realtek 81xx Ethernet controllers by launching Lnx2Mac's Installer which installs RealtekRTL81xx.kext in /System/Library/Extensions. Here's the link if anyone encounters this problems.

[Lnx2Mac's RealtekRTL81xx-0_0_90.pkg](http://bit.ly/pLlD13)

Also check out there blog for any further questions or tips

http://lnx2mac.blogspot.com.au/